# Can tamed pets accidentally teleport into lava?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been having an issue with my dogs. Specifically, they keep dying while locked up tight in my fortress.

I've got a few levels, each three blocks high. As I'm going up and down doing stuff, my dogs follow me, but *occasionally* I hear one die rather quickly. My first thought was to blame Endermen, since I am building three high, they can easily have the run of the place. However, after placing a command block to zap those creepy dudes from existence every few ticks, the problem is persisting. Nothing else can spawn inside, I've checked and re-checked every nook.

I then had a bit of an epiphany:

[image]

(Don't mind the command blocks, they're just a convenient mode of transportation as I work on a very large adventure map I'm building - the lava was just an experiment with using lava for lighting)

Is it possible for pets to accidentally teleport into lava while trying to follow you? I can't figure out what else is killing my dogs so randomly.

Comment: Maybe you could build a larger "landing area" for the pets to land instead of being so close to the lava, even though there is glass containing the lava.

Comment: If you're using a Craftbukkit server, the Worldguard plugin has a flag called "Anti-wolf-stupidity". It makes wolves immune to environmental damage like drowning / lava.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they can. I've gone into dangerous mines many times, thinking my dogs were safe and sound in my home, when I see one of them randomly teleport into the lava pit in front of me. To remedy it, (here comes the solution part) I usually make the dogs sit down because after that they won't move. At all. It's absolutely perfect for going to my obsidian mine, situated ON AN ACTIVE LAVA LAKE, home to the graves of many dogs.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they can. Pets currently don't do a good job of picking landing spots when they teleport. I've recently seen a video of some of the Mindcrackers using that to kill cats that another player had placed by causing them to teleport to where he was, which was over a lava pit. When the cats teleported, they fell in the lava.

The video can be seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=20fsQB5xcUQ&index=80&list=PL7j0JO-w0xWm1ecVc1G0bco7auS7zzoxh) if you're curious as to how it happened.